# Dynamically reference external cells using concatenation in Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, external

I have a workbook in which I am trying to pull data into from an external excel document.

Ideally I would like to specify a file path in the master workbook, which is the location to pull data from and then use another cell to determine what cell inside that filepath to look for.

For example:

- Cell A1 = C:\Documents\book.xlsx *(the file path)*
- Cell A2 = sheet3 *(the sheet inside book.xlsx that I want to look at)*
- Cell A3 = H8 *(the cell I want to retrieve from book.xlsx*)

Is there a way I can then pull these together to create a reference to that cell, using CONCATENATE and INDIRECT at the moment but it is just giving me a #REF error.

E.g.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[", A1, "]", A2, "!", A3))
```

(would be giving a value of [C:\Documents\book.xlsx]sheet3!H8)

Comment: With INDIRECT() the workbook needs to be opened for it to update the value.

Comment: Workbook is open and still will not reference through.

Answer (score 0):

Used an article from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629-macro-read-cell-value-external-file-xls.html) to fix this, using this code:

```
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:TempBook1.xls")
MsgBox WBK.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

WBK.Close
Set XL = Nothing
```